# An outstanding challenge to get my Wifi to work on my Laptop... I need a new fresh idea do you have it?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, acer

So the laptop is Acer Aspire 5710z running 12.04

here is the lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 3 (rev 02)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5787M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)
05:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
06:00.0 FLASH memory: ENE Technology Inc ENE PCI Memory Stick Card Reader Controller
06:00.1 SD Host controller: ENE Technology Inc ENE PCI SmartMedia / xD Card Reader Controller
06:00.2 FLASH memory: ENE Technology Inc Memory Stick Card Reader Controller
06:00.3 FLASH memory: ENE Technology Inc ENE PCI Secure Digital / MMC Card Reader Controller
```

then sudo lspci -nnk -s 05:00.0

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AMBIT Microsystem Corp. Device [1468:0422]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: ssb
```

then

```
annette@annette-Aspire-5710Z:~$ sudo rfkill list all
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
annette@annette-Aspire-5710Z:~$
```

and why not

```
annette@annette-Aspire-5710Z:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:38:23:58:93  
          inet addr:192.168.178.56  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21b:38ff:fe23:5893/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:388530 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:205406 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:564817042 (564.8 MB)  TX bytes:17587353 (17.5 MB)
          Interrupt:18 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:12307 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12307 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1012956 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:1012956 (1.0 MB)
```

I hope this gives you a start.

I am willing to do any and all methods that have worked for you before... currently i am downloading 13.10 as a last attempt at a complete system restart or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fresh, new idea. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and let us hear your report.

Comment: download seemed to work and said it was installed...   re booting shortly my friend.. thanks for the answer

just waiting for the last of 13.10 to download, last time i broke the connection it wouldnt pick up the download again and i had to start again

Comment: oh my lord you did it!

after asking for help through 3 differnent questions and following numerous processes your 5 minute install worked!

how do i mark as your answer did it???     im gonna share this with other acer users having trouble   cheers again!!!

Comment: ah, just found it, for some reason i didnt have enough reputation before...   but yes thanks again mate.

Comment: can i ask you what did you find usefull in the information i provided?
or did you just know that command from a previous issue?

Comment: I know the required solution from the device ID 14e4:4311 from many years of experience. Practice makes perfect. I also keep many notes.

Comment: ah ok, so it had nothing to do with the laptop itself but the wlan card... correct?   or more acurately the firmware associated with it

Comment: Exactly. Proprietary firmware is not packaged along with the default open source install of Ubuntu and, for some devices, including 14e4:4311, must be added separately.